# CakePHP 2.0 Acl + Auth + custom username field

Tags: cakephp, authentication, acl

in my AppController I have this setup

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
     ),
    'Session',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

In my User model I have no "username" field, I have "email" so I changed the $components config to:

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'Session',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

In this way I don't get the error "Model has no field 'username'" but my login is rejected.
So I switched back to previous configuration, altered the table

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN username email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL UNIQUE;
```

And it worked.. so what's wrong with my previous configuration?

Comment: The query you display is necessary, because you are changing the `username` column to `email`, which is exactly as you describe you want it to? If that was a paste mistake and it's actually the other way around, make sure your view also has the `User.email` input field, rather than copy/pasting the `User.username` example from the tutorial.

Comment: What I don't understand is why with "authenticate" configuration is not running any query on users to check credentials and immediately reject authentication

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @Oldskool tip I reverted to

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'Session',
    'DebugKit.Toolbar'
);
```

Then I changed the login view too (replacing username with email):

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
  'legend' => __('Login'),
  'email',
  'password'
));
```

I thought that the login form was managed by auth component and not by User model, and that the mapping between username and email was to be done only in Auth component configuration

Comment: The fieldnames you use in your View should pretty much always match the fieldnames used in your database, so this should now do the trick.

Comment: that's clear, I just thought they were managed by the Auth component in login pahse, but I was wrong :)